# copy a large array from vb.net application to a datasheet of ms office chart

Tags: vb.net, charts, ms-word

There are many examples about filling a datasheet of ms word chart cell by cell:

```
oSheet.Cells(i, j) = myarray(i,j)
```

but in a case of a large array such filling tends to infinity.
At the same time excel allows to fill his datasheet immediately:

```
oSheet.Range("A1", "Z5000").Value = myarray
```

but solution for excel not works for ms word in this form.

Is it possible to fill a datasheet in word as in excel?